# lists and converting user inputs in python 3.6

Tags: list, python-3.x, input

Hi there i cannot figure out how to get my total shopping price to add together and show the total. Ive search for this and i cant find what im looking for :(
thank you!

```
print("Hello this is your shopping list!")

shopList = []
shoppingTotal = []
sumOfAllNumbers = sum(shoppingTotal)

maxLengthList = 2
while len(shopList) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("what do you need today? Add your item: ")
    shopList.append(item)
    price = int(input("How much can you spend?"))
    shoppingTotal.append(price)
    print(shopList)
    print(shoppingTotal)
print("This is your shopping list")
print(shopList)
print(sumOfAllNumbers + 'This will be your budget for today')
```

Comment: What is your expected input and output? What did you get? What's your question? BTW you are `sum`ing an empty list if you `sum` before your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you've defined `sumOfAllNumbers` before having a full list. When you say:

```
sumOfAllNumbers = sum(shoppingTotal)
```

`sumOfAllNumbers` will be set to the sum of all values in the list `shoppingTotal` *at the moment you set it*. In your code, you are doing:

```
shoppingTotal = []
sumOfAllNumbers = sum(shoppingTotal)
```

replacing variables by their values, we can see that what you are doing is:

sumOfAllNumbers = sum([])

which is obviously 0.

What you should do is sum the list up **after** you've added the prices to it.

In addition, you can't add sumOfAllNumbers to a string directly - while both numbers and strings can be added, Python won't automatically convert a value in order to add it to another one - so you need to convert sumOfAllNumbers by hand first, using the `str()` function.

So your code should look like:

```
print("Hello this is your shopping list!")

shopList = []
shoppingTotal = []

maxLengthList = 2
while len(shopList) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("what do you need today? Add your item: ")
    shopList.append(item)
    price = int(input("How much can you spend?"))
    shoppingTotal.append(price)
    print(shopList)
    print(shoppingTotal)


print("This is your shopping list")
print(shopList)

sumOfAllNumbers = sum(shoppingTotal)
print(str(sumOfAllNumbers) + 'This will be your budget for today')
```

In addition, one final point: Your variable names aren't very Pythonic. The usual practice in Python is to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`. So `sumOfAllNumbers` should be called `sum_of_all_numbers`.

Comment: If I have managed to help you, please accept and upvote my answer :)

Comment: THis is actaully still giving me the same error as before....                   Traceback (most recent call last):
[5, 3]
  File "C:/Users/tyler/PycharmProjects/Grocery list/Lists.py", line 19, in <module>
This is your shopping list
    print(sumOfAllNumbers + 'This will be your budget for today')
['Pie', 'Eggs']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Oh, I forgot that little detail. 

When you use `+` to add one value to another, you need to ensure both values are the same type. So even though you can add `int`s to `int`s and `str`s to `str`s, you can't add an `int` to an `str`. What you want to do is join the number to the string, so you should do:

    `print(str(sumOfAllNumbers) + 'This will be your budget for today')`

Comment: I edited my answer to amend this error and also added some info about proper variable names.